# CSS to vertically align text in middle position beside a large checkbox

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

I want to have a checkbox 2em high, 2em wide, and next to it some extra small text in parentheses: `(check box to agree to these terms)`

```
xxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxx∎x
xxxxxxx∎xxx
xxxxxx∎xxxx  (check box to agree to these terms)
x∎xx∎xxxxxx  
xxx∎xxxxxxx
```

```css
#container {
  height: 3em
}
input {
  height: 2em;
  width: 2em
}
.legal {
  vertical-align: middle
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <input type="checkbox">
  <div class="legal">(check box to agree to these terms)</div>
  <div>
```

I've not had any success getting the text to move vertically by enclosing both in a container div, setting its height, and using `vertical-align: middle` on the text.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: But I have not succeeded in doing anything. Which one of my failed attempts would you like to see???????  I've described what I've done code-wise. What's to be "verified" here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to do it- see some of them below:

**Solution 1**: *Inline-block*

Use `inline-block` for both the `input` and the `legal` elements and vertically align them to the middle:

```css
#container {
  height: 3em
}
input {
  height: 2em;
  width: 2em;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.legal {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <input type="checkbox">
  <div class="legal">(check box to agree to these terms)</div>
  <div>
```

**Solution 2**: *Table display*

Use `table` for the container and `table-cell` for both the `input` and the `legal` elements:

```css
#container {
  height: 3em;
  display: table;
}
input {
  height: 2em;
  width: 2em;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.legal {
  display: table-cell;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <input type="checkbox">
  <div class="legal">(check box to agree to these terms)</div>
  <div>
```

**Solution 3**: *Flexbox*

Simply use `flex` for the container and use `align-items: center` to vertically center them:

```css
#container {
  height: 3em;
  display: flex;
align-items: center;
}
input {
  height: 2em;
  width: 2em;
}
.legal {
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <input type="checkbox">
  <div class="legal">(check box to agree to these terms)</div>
  <div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The term div should have `display:inline-block;`since you want to make it in line with checkbox. the container should have a `line-height` instead of `height` because `vertical-align` only work with `line-height`

```
#container {
  line-height: 3em;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
input {
  height: 2em;
  width: 2em;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.legal {
  display:inline-block;
  width:auto;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/2twhpyy9/2/